# Why any mailers I use opens my default text editor instead of another browser tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

So I am testing a mailer gem(letter_opener) for my app to view emails on the browser.

So i have my notifications_controller(generated by scaffolding).

Then my mailer:

```
            notification_mailer
                    class NotificationMailer < ApplicationMailer
              default to:       -> { "somelist@postbox.tu" },
                      from:     -> { "info@postbox.tut" }

              def notification_mailer(notification)
                @notification = notification
                @url  = "http://postbox.tut/"
                mail(:subject => "New Notification")
              end
            end
```

This is my views/notification_mailer/notification_mailer view

```
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></pre>
            <h1>Notification email.</h1>
            <h2><%= @notification.headline %></h2>
            <pre>
            <%= @notification.content %>

            This email was sent out to you, because you are subscribed to the postbox-mailing-list.
            If you want to unscribscribe, please use this url: <%= @url %>.
```

Instead of opening a new tab (containing the rendered email) like I'm having yesterday now I can't. But my rails console says:

```
            Started POST "/notifications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-10 15:17:56 +0800
            Processing by NotificationsController#create as HTML
              Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MgfddL8EHhDylDDVHqsvYLlQ2HO0fB1J9amMpty1HDqsjJGCJx0fpBfnlvRVeOUtxMc8Seq8L8lsxeZeGg3Aww==", "notification"=>{"headline"=>"Don", "content"=>"pogi pogi no mi\r\n"}, "commit"=>"Create Notification"}
              Rendering notification_mailer/notification_mailer.html.erb within layouts/mailer
              Rendered notification_mailer/notification_mailer.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.7ms)
            NotificationMailer#notification_mailer: processed outbound mail in 33.5ms
            Sent mail to somelist@postbox.tu (23.4ms)
            Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 15:17:56 +0800
            From: info@postbox.tut
            To: somelist@postbox.tu
            Message-ID: <5bbda7a42ca92_5e7f2b0fe9be8a10789b3@don-300E4C-300E5C-300E7C.mail>
            Subject: New Notification
            Mime-Version: 1.0
            Content-Type: text/html;
            charset=UTF-8
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <style>
                  /* Email styles need to be inline */
                </style>
              </head>

              <body>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></pre>
            <h1>Notification email.</h1>
            <h2>Don</h2>
            <pre>
            pogi pogi no mi


            This email was sent out to you, because you are subscribed to the postbox-mailing-list.
            If you want to unscribscribe, please use this url: http://postbox.tut/.
              </body>
            </html>
```

Checking my tmp folder the mail is being generated. Now what's happening is no browser is being opened but a blank visual studio code file always opened after creating a new post.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this one out. Seems like I accidentally changed my default html viewer into my text editor.